# C# - How to prevent a subclass from calling protected methods directly by itself?

Tags: c#, oop

My code:

```
abstract class StateMachine {
    protected string State { get; private set; }
    protected abstract void OnWorking();
    protected abstract void OnPrepare();
    protected abstract void OnCancel();

    public bool Prepare() {
        if(State != null) {
            return false;
        }
        State = "Preparing";
        OnPrepare();
        State = "Prepared";
        return true;
    }
    public bool Start() {
        if(State != "Prepared") {
            return false;
        }
        State = "Working";
        OnWorking();
        State = "Done";
        return true;
    }
    public bool Cancel() {
        if(State != "Working" || State == "Done") {
            return false;
        }
        OnCancel();
        State = "Canceled";
        return true;
    }
}

class Downloader : StateMachine {
    protected override void OnPrepare() {
        Console.WriteLine("I am preparing.");
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
    protected override void OnWorking() {
        Console.WriteLine("I am working.");
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
    protected override void OnCancel() {
        Console.WriteLine("Let's cancel the operation!");
    }
}

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        Downloader downloader = new Downloader();
        Parallel.Invoke(() => {
            downloader.Prepare();
            downloader.Start();
        }, () => {
            // Cancel while working
            Thread.Sleep(1500);
            downloader.Cancel();
        });
    }
}
```

The output would be:

```
I am preparing.
I am working.
Let's cancel the operation!
```

Now I am building the `StateMachine` class and it works very well. It allows subclasses to not care about the current states at all, which is awesome because handling states of a process is a huge pain in the head.

The problem is though, nothing can't stop the subclass (`Downloader`) from calling those protected methods in the base class (`StateMachine`) by itself. For example, a subclass can have something like:

```
protected override void OnWorking(){
    Console.WriteLine("I am working.");
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    OnCancel();
    OnPrepare();
}
```

Then the output would be:

```
I am preparing.
I am working.
Let's cancel the operation!
I am preparing.
Let's cancel the operation!
```

Which is not expected from the `StateMachine`'s point of view.

So I am trying to prevent the subclass from calling protected methods. But I feel like I am doing a weird thing. I don't think C# OOP concepts would allow this behavior.

I don't mean to make these protected methods invisible from the subclass though. I'm more about throwing exceptions if subclasses do that. Maybe I need to add extra logic in the base class the handle this. But that might makes the code messy.

What would you do in this situation? I mean, what might be the elegant way to solve this?

Comment: Hi, Do you want to prevent the implementation of a method in subclass ?

Comment: I feel this is an XY problem. What you are asking for is not possible, but the problem caused by subclasses calling protected methods could possibly be solved. What’s the real problem here?

Comment: @weichch I'm sorry for not being clear. I think there are still ways to achieve my goal. But I meant what might be the elegant way to do this. Reflection? Custom attributes? I don't know. Anything helps.

Comment: You make methods protected meaning they are visible to derived classes. Once they are visible, it is not possible to stop the derived classes from calling them. Generally if the protected methods do not change any shared state between derived and base class, calling them shouldn’t be a problem. If they change the state in base class, for example, calling them resets state machines state, then you have other ways to stop that happening.

Comment: Though, btw, if you really want to do this, you can implement your own Roslyn analyzers that scan the code and generate compile time errors. Just there’s always ways people can workaround the analyzers :)

Comment: If you don't want `protected` methods to be called from derived classes, make them `private` :)

Answer (score 1):

You can define them as delegates and make them private, and set them with abstract helper methods as follow:

```
static void Main()
{
  Downloader downloader = new Downloader();
  Parallel.Invoke(() =>
  {
    downloader.Prepare();
    downloader.Start();
  }, () =>
  {
    // Cancel while working
    Thread.Sleep(1500);
    downloader.Cancel();
  });
}

abstract class StateMachine
{
  protected string State { get; private set; }

  private Action OnWorking;
  private Action OnPrepare;
  private Action OnCancel;

  // Helper methods to be implemented in subclass
  protected abstract Action DefineWorkingAction();
  protected abstract Action DefinePrepareAction();
  protected abstract Action DefineCancelAction();

  protected StateMachine()
  {
    this.OnWorking = DefineWorkingAction();
    this.OnPrepare = DefinePrepareAction();
    this.OnCancel = DefineCancelAction();
  }


  public bool Prepare()
  {
    if (State != null)
    {
      return false;
    }
    State = "Preparing";
    OnPrepare();
    State = "Prepared";
    return true;
  }
  public bool Start()
  {
    if (State != "Prepared")
    {
      return false;
    }
    State = "Working";
    OnWorking();
    State = "Done";
    return true;
  }
  public bool Cancel()
  {
    if (State != "Working" || State == "Done")
    {
      return false;
    }
    OnCancel();
    State = "Canceled";
    return true;
  }
}

class Downloader : StateMachine
{
  protected override  Action DefineWorkingAction()
  {
    return () =>
    {
      Console.WriteLine("I am working.");
      Thread.Sleep(1000);
    };
  }

  protected  override Action DefinePrepareAction()
  {
    return () =>
    {
      Console.WriteLine("I am preparing.");
      Thread.Sleep(1000);
    };
  }

  protected  override Action DefineCancelAction()
  {
    return () =>
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Let's cancel the operation!");
    };
  }
}
```

Now subclasses cannot call them anymore.